# In MongoDB, what is the time complexity of a query to find all records with row ids not in a given list?

Tags: sql, database, mongodb, performance, nosql

I have a pre defined array, A,  containing an arbitrary number of row ids for a particular table.

The query is to find all records / rows of this table that have row ids not contained in A.

What is the time complexity of this query?

The row id is the primary key of this table. Thus, it is indexed?

Comment: recently that i tested an aggregation with `$in` its complexity was O(m) m members of the array, so i guess mxn  (n records)(collection scan) or mxlogn (index scan) i am not sure of those. You can test it, also with big or small list, i think big => more time, at least from the tests i did.  Seems like MongoDB don't uses sets internally, and does serial search on arrays to find if contains or not.

Answer (score 1):

O(n)

Directly dependant on the amount of records in the collection.

If no index can be used, O(n).
If indexes can be used, indexes are b-tree.
So it would be O(log n).

There could be edge cases as well - but I think the above covers most cases.

If you want to get some interesting details about your queries/indexes - check out explain - which is a method that returns useful details of the query/indexes used to return the results.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/introduction-of-b-tree-2/

Comment: The query is on the record id itself. Wouldn't the record id always by default be an index?

Comment: @free_lions_n_tigers_from_cages updated answer.

Comment: Why is it `log(n)` and not `m*log(n)`, where `m` is the length of the array that contains the records?

Comment: @free_lions_n_tigers_from_cages - indexes in MongoDB are b-tree. 
B-Tree grows and shrinks from the root. Like other balanced Binary Search Trees, time complexity to search, insert and delete is O(log n)

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/introduction-of-b-tree-2/